# Why do we use “listens” instead of “listen” in this tag question?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I have found the use of *audience* in tag question which confused me. The  sentence is

> The audience listens to the bagpipes.

Then it has to be changed into tag question. The answer key said: "The audience listens to the bagpipes, don't they?"

Is it correct? If the audience is considered as a group of people, why does the sentence use "listens" instead of "listen"?

Answer (score 2):

> If the audience is considered as a group of people

This is true, but *audience* is still a singular noun.  Because it refers to a single group, not multiple groups.

> The audiences listen to the bagpipes

There's where you'd use the plural noun form.

*People* means "multiple persons" (plural of *person*)

> The people listen to the bagpipes

---

> Then it has to be changed into tag question. The answer key said: "The audience listens to the bagpipes, don't they?"

*It* is an impersonal pronoun and can't be used to refer to people.  This is a strongly observed convention in English.

Another situation where you really need a pronoun--but English is unhelpful--is if you don't know whether to choose between *him* or *her* - *they*/*their*/*them* has a tendency to be used.  This is the "singular they" and the Wikipedia article shows examples of its use from the 1300's.

> A potential employee would need to have passed their drug test to get hired (do not know whether employee is male or female).

"The audience listens to the bagpipes, doesn't it?" is not wrong, but since an audience is comprised of people, the temptation to do a similar thing to the "singular they" is strong.

It avoids any allusion that *it* might refer to the nearest non-human object, which are the bagpipes, to someone who isn't listening closely.  Someone might even think *doesn't it* refers to something earlier in the conversation they may have missed.

Comment: And this is a perfect example of why English is illogical. I've heard both "the audience listen" and "the audience listens" (the latter is more common) and both "doesn't it?" and "don't they?" *can* be used, even where there is a lack of agreement with the "rule" used in the first part. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford the first part is largely a dialect issue—British English tends to use the plural with groups ("Arsenal are footballers"), but American English almost always uses the singular ("Arsenal is a soccer team"). Though even Americans may use the plural for the ending confirmation depending on context ("Arsenal is on fire today, aren't they?")